# How to configure icon for my flutter web application?

Tags: flutter

I am experimenting with flutter for web and cannot find information how to configure the icon.

It should be possible, because [taphero_web](https://github.com/mkiisoft/taphero_web) did it somehow. I reviewed their sources and could not find the image they have for the site:

[image]

I host my app with codemagic.io.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Glad you ask! As the owner of that project I can tell you how I did it:

**UPDATE: With PWA support and Flutter 3**

1- Inside your `/web` folder (to be pushed to the server), add a /icons folder (if your don't have it already).

2- Once you're there, you need to upload your set of images with websites like [this one](https://www.favicon-generator.org/).

3- Is going to look something like this:

[image: Icons Folder]

4- You should have a `manifest.json` and is going to look something like this:

```json
{
    "name": "Tap Hero",
    "short_name": "Tap Hero",
    "start_url": ".",
    "display": "standalone",
    "background_color": "#000000", // any HEX color works
    "theme_color": "#000000", // any HEX color works
    "description": "anything you want here",
    "orientation": "portrait" // or changed as you wish
    "prefer_related_application": false,
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "\/icons/android-icon-36x36.png",
            "sizes": "36x36",
            "type": "image\/png",
            "density": "0.75"
        },
        {
            "src": "\/icons/android-icon-48x48.png",
            "sizes": "48x48",
            "type": "image\/png",
            "density": "1.0"
        },
        {
            "src": "\/icons/android-icon-72x72.png",
            "sizes": "72x72",
            "type": "image\/png",
            "density": "1.5"
        },
        {
            "src": "\/icons/android-icon-96x96.png",
            "sizes": "96x96",
            "type": "image\/png",
            "density": "2.0"
        },
        {
            "src": "\/icons/android-icon-144x144.png",
            "sizes": "144x144",
            "type": "image\/png",
            "density": "3.0"
        },
        {
            "src": "\/icons/android-icon-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image\/png",
            "density": "4.0"
        }
    ]
}
```

5- Once you did all that, add the rest of the icons inside your `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tap Hero</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Tap Hero">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Flutter, Tap, Hero, Game">
    <meta name="author" content="Mariano Zorrilla">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#6200EA" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="icons/apple-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="icons/apple-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="icons/apple-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="icons/apple-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="icons/apple-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="icons/apple-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="icons/apple-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="icons/apple-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="icons/apple-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="icons/android-icon-192x192.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="icons/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="icons/favicon-96x96.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="icons/favicon-16x16.png">

    <!-- Main Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/pg" href="favicon/png"/>

    <!-- ALTERNATIVE <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" /> -->
    
    <link rel="manifest" href="icons/manifest.json">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#6200EA">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="icons/ms-icon-144x144.png">
    <script>
       if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
         window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
           navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
         });
       }
    </script>
    <script defer src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

6. IF (by any chance) your `/web` and or `manifest.json` files are corrupted/broken/etc you can delete the entire file and do "flutter create ." that will generate everything again for you and can do a new try every single time.

Comment: Thanks. I use codemagic for hosting. So I assume the 'folder to be pushed to the server' is 'Web'.

Comment: Yes, I used the link I posted here for the assets ("this one"): https://www.favicon-generator.org/

The 'folder to be pushed to the server' is the one holding your index.html, etc the one generated after doing the webdev build

Comment: what does density mean in manifest.json, is it like 1.0x, 2.0x assets for mobile?

Answer (score 42):

I started following the instructions in Mariano Zorilla's answer but found it is much simpler if you only want to set the Favicon for your Flutter Web App.

1. Upload your image in an icon-creating website [like the one Mariano suggested](https://www.favicon-generator.org/).

2. Select the **"Generate only 16x16 favicon.ico"** option and download the icon file.
3. In `web/` folder, replace the default flutter `favicon.png` with you new generated `favicon.ico` file
4. In `web/index.html` file,

replace:

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>
```

with:

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: With this solution, will 'Save Icon to Home Screen' work? Or it just to show a small icon on the URL bar only?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel

Comment: >Note: The `shortcut` link type is often seen before `icon`, but this link type is non-conforming, ignored and **web authors must not use it anymore.**

Answer (score 32):

To configure your favicon for flutter web, just replace the file at path `./web/favicon.png` with your own icon and then run `flutter build web`.

Comment: Just wanna emphasis what Banana says. Make sure to rebuild the flutter app if its currently running. I had the app already running and made the changes and nothing was happening on just the refreshes

Comment: Since I did this I get the following errors ``Expected to find fonts for (MaterialIcons, packages/cupertino_icons/CupertinoIcons), but found (MaterialIcons). This usually means you are referring to font
families in an IconData class but not including them in the assets section of your pubspec.yaml, are missing the package that would include them, or are missing
"uses-material-design: true``

Comment: and ``Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184 to 7588 bytes (99.5% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the
--no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
``

Comment: I have been searching for a solution, but have not found one yet ``flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1889], locale en-ZA)
    • Flutter version 3.13.0 on channel stable at C:\src\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision efbf63d9c6 (6 weeks ago), 2023-08-15 21:05:06 -0500
    • Engine revision 1ac611c64e
    • Dart version 3.1.0
``

Answer (score 1):

just use the same dimensions and the icon names with the respect of the size and add your own icons and overwrite the generated ones..

I have used https://romannurik.github.io/ and it's quite satisfying for me since i started my journey in android and then flutter to generate the icons and also android icons ...

Comment: Updated and preferred one is https://icon.kitchen/

Answer (score 1):

In your project, go to the root of your project and replace

- `/web/favicon.png` with a 32*32 image
- `/web/icons/Icon-192.png` with a 192*192 image
- `/web/icons/Icon-512.png` with a 512*512 image
- `/web/icons/Icon-maskable-192.png` with a 192*192 image
- `/web/icons/Icon-maskable-512.png` with a 512*512 image

`flutter build web` should now always take those files.

This also considers the `Install app` functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Also as an option you can use this package to manage icons all over Flutter app platforms [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons)

it will do everything you need after specifying icons configuration and running command `flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main` or `dart run flutter_launcher_icons:main`